# Easaeljs game project

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

In the following link [basket](http://jaketesting.altervista.org/basket/) I create a game but everything disappeared. Right now I have no clue why. I hope someone could see into the code just inspecting for give some advice.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I get the following error in the *debug console*.

**GET http://jaketesting.altervista.org/basket/src/Box2DClasses.js 404 (Not Found)**

It can't find your `box2d` javascript file.

Comment: Now is there but still same problem [link](http://jaketesting.altervista.org/src/Box2dClasses.js)

Comment: I recive this 2 errors ReferenceError: b2ContactListener is not defined @Aesthete
 

var P = ContactCallBack.prototype = new b2ContactListener();

Contac...Back.js (line 6)
ReferenceError: b2World is not defined
 

...dWorld = new b2World(new b2Vec2(0,CONST.gravity), false); //TODO : turn it on ma...
World.js (line 31)